# color coded if statement contradicting itself

Tags: java, if-statement, colors, bots

if statement not working for color conditions

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class TestColor {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws AWTException {
        Robot Bot = new Robot();

        if(Bot.getPixelColor(1003, 185)==Bot.getPixelColor(1003, 185)) {
            System.out.println("True");
        }else {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
    }
}
```

and i got a result of:

False

Answer (score 0):

`getPixelColor()` returns a `Color` object, `==` for two objects tests if the object reference is the same, `c1.equals(c2)` test if the values of the object are the same (where `c1` and `c2` are `Color` objects).